# Receive 3 Broadcasts When the Network Switched from GPRS to Wifi

Tags: android

When the network switched from GPRS to Wifi, I received 3 times of Broadcast of android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE.

In onReceive(), I use the code below to judge whether Wifi connected. But I also received 3 times of message of "Wifi Connected", and doSomething() was called 3 times.

```
ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo wifiInfo = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
if(wifiInfo.isConnected()) {
    Log.v(Constant.APP_NAME, "Wifi Connected.");
    doSomething();
}
```

I want to receive only ONE message of "Wifi Connected", and call doSomething() only ONCE.
How should I do?

Thank you. And sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a boolean flag value that checks for the messsage
make it static if you want it to be accessable from some wehere else
Eg

```
public static boolean flagConnected = false;

ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo wifiInfo = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
if(wifiInfo.isConnected() && flagConnected == false) {
flagConnected = true;
Log.v(Constant.APP_NAME, "Wifi Connected.");
doSomething();
}
```

After doSomething(); you can change the value of the flag to false again

```
ClassName.flagConnected = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare an integer variable in your Receiver class...

public static int i=0;

and place your code in this condition

```
if((++i)%3==1){
//your whole stuff here..
}
```

Comment: OK...But not alway 3 times...Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might forgot to unregister your broadcastreceiver in your onPause / onStop.

Comment: But I want to receive the broadcast forever...Thank you.